# Laravel dropbox initial value on update

Tags: laravel, sql-update, html-select, dropbox, dropdown

Items belongs to Categories. On edit page for Items I have an html select with Categories. Is this the best solution to have the right initial state for this select?

```
<select name="id_category" class="form-control">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        @if($category->id == $item->id_category)
            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">
                {{ $category->name }}
            </option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        @if($category->id != $item->id_category)
            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">
                {{ $category->name }}
            </option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site! For code review please visit https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, didn't knew bout this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand your question, but i think you want to select item was previously select by user, so you can use inline if to set selected.

```
<select name="id_category" class="form-control">
     @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{  $category->id == $item->id_category ? "selected" : "" }} >
            {{ $category->name }}
        </option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

Sorry if i didn't understand your question

Comment: Yes, that's perfect solution. Thank you.